# How to run package.json from another repo using Python (lib pynpm)?

Tags: python, node.js, npm, package, subprocess

I want to get file from another repo to use in my code.
Also I found that Python has a pynpm lib like this:

```
from pynpm import NPMPackage
pkg = NPMPackage('path')
```

but it's not work, also I used the token to get file by api, but it's bad practice to download every time this file.
So, Do you know how to import file using npm in Python or run package.json from another repo.
Because I know that in JS we can use like this:

```
import * as schema from '@project/.../.../.../.../file_name.json';
```